# Issue with MySQL database connection after importing it

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a program on my working machine which uses MySQL. On that machine everything works fine.

So I exported the database with MySQL Workbench 6.3 with "Export to self-contained file" Everything worked smooth.

On my home server I installed exactly the same version of MySQL. All the same.

But if I want to execute my program on that server I always receive that message:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2017-07-28 22:16:44.293  INFO 8624 --- [           main] com.algotest.DemoApplication             : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP
-JHL7NBI with PID 8624 (C:\Dropbox\Projects\AlgoTest\Jar\Server\AlgoTest.jar started by Server in C:\Dropbox\Projects\AlgoTest\Jar\Serv
er)
2017-07-28 22:16:44.295  INFO 8624 --- [           main] com.algotest.DemoApplication             : No active profile set, falling back
 to default profiles: default
2017-07-28 22:16:44.326  INFO 8624 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.cont
ext.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@8df31b: startup date [Fri Jul 28 22:16:44 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-28 22:16:48.992 ERROR 8624 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connection
s of pool.

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:526) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1677) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.15.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.
3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.
RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) [spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.
RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure
-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconf
igure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105) [spring-
boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb95dfe1.CGLIB$jpaVendo
rAdapter$5(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb95dfe1$$FastClassBySp
ringCGLIB$$6b52e508.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer
.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bb95dfe1.jpaVendorAdapt
er(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spr
ing-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [s
pring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
ava:483) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.9.
RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [
spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RE
LEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELE
ASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-
4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:113
8) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
 [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring
-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-bean
s-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [s
pring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
ava:483) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.9.
RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [
spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RE
LEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELE
ASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-
4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:113
8) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
 [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring
-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-bean
s-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [s
pring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanF
actory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
ava:483) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.9.
RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [
spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RE
LEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELE
ASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) [spring-context
-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.ja
va:857) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-
4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.R
ELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at com.algotest.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:27) [AlgoTest.jar:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJException: Access denied for user 'springuser'@'localhost' to database 'db_example'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:54) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0
.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:93) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0
.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:133) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.
0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.
0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.checkErrorPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:807) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.checkErrorPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:732) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.checkErrorPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:701) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.authentication.MysqlaAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlaAuthentica
tionProvider.java:536) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.authentication.MysqlaAuthenticationProvider.connect(MysqlaAuthenticationProvider.java:204) ~[mysql-conne
ctor-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.connect(MysqlaProtocol.java:1414) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
        ... 76 common frames omitted

2017-07-28 22:16:49.001  WARN 8624 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from d
atasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.sp
ringframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnect
ionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData
```

The reponse is a bit longer but I cannot copy all of it here, Stackoverflow doesn't allow so much charts. So if there is something missing, please tell me.

So, to just be sure I tried to change the logins on the server with:

```
DROP USER 'springuser'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'springuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

which was succesful.

But still I receive that error message. I also restarted the server, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue with old Workbench syntax.

Try:

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```